# Iterate through sheets in Pyexcel in python

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I want to iterate through all the non empty sheets of Excel to get the headers. I must use PyExcel for that.Here is my code:

```
import pyexcel as pe
book = pe.get_book(file_name="Mydata.xlsx")




j=0
print(j)
for j in range(100):
    for item in book.sheet_by_index(j):

     sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="Mydata.xlsx")
     sheetheaders= sheet.row_at(0)
     header_list = [i for i in sheetheaders if i != '' ]

     print(header_list)
     j=j+1
```

Can anyone help me by telling how do I iterate it without getting following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 11, in <module>
    for sheet in book[i]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thank you!

Comment: The sheets' indexes are most probably zero-based. Try setting `i` to 0.

Comment: Intialize i with i=0

Comment: It's complaining `sheeheaders` is `None`. Are you sure you didn't misspell `shee*t*headers`? Where is this variable defined? Did you mean maybe `header_list = [header for header in sheet]`?

Comment: Where is `book[i]`? Can you paste your whole code at once?

Comment: Hi,I updated the code. it is not going to second sheet. It is iterating in first sheet and giving those headers again and again.

Comment: @darksky: I updated the code. Book[i] was a mistake. I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
import pyexcel as p

header_list = [[ a_header for a_header in sheet.row[0] if a_header] for sheet in p.get_book(file_name="my file.xlsx") if sheet.number_of_rows() > 0]
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! This package made my life much easier!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. It's my pleasure!

Comment: Hi, it worked but I am getting ' ' in output list as an item. I tried using>>>>>>>> '~[a for a in header_list if len( a ) > 0]~' but it didn't work. example:::::::: char=[a,v,b,' ', ' ']

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to increment the index manually in a for loop. Try the following code:

```
for sheet_index in range(book.number_of_sheets()):
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
    header_list = [header for header in sheet.row_at(0)]

    print(header_list)
```